# ffmpeg .mkv to .mkv with audio .aac compression

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, aac, bitrate, matroska

I am trying to use ffmpeg on a `.mkv` video to change soundtrack quality. I would like to lower the bitrate of the audio part (to 16 kbps) without any modification of the video. Nevertheless when I use the ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -b:a 16k output.mkv
```

the sound is not changed and the video is compressed. I tried

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -ab 16k output.mkv
```

and had same problem. When I tried

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -ab 16k -acodec aac -strict experimental output.mkv
```

I got the error:

```
oggvorbis_encode_init: init_encoder failed
```

Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Try extracting the audio stream with `mkvextract` first and working with it seperately.  You can remux the new audio track and the original MKV file with `mkvmerge`.

Answer (score 2):

By default ffmpeg will re-encode any streams that have not been explicitly selected for [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode, and the default video encoding bitrate (depending on the encoder) may be too low to provide an adequate output quality. Instead of re-encoding you can copy the video with `-codec:v copy` as an output option.

For such a low audio bitrate I recommend using an AAC encoder that supports HE-AAC. This example is adapted from the [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) and will use approximately 16kb/s per channel for a stereo output:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -codec:v copy -codec:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he_v2 -b:a 32k output.mkv
```

Depending on what the content of your input audio is such a low bitrate will probably not sound that great even with this encoder. Note that HE-AACv2 [may not be supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Efficiency_Advanced_Audio_Coding#Decoding) by your targeted decoder(s), and you will probably have to [compile ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide) for `libfdk_aac` support.

Opus audio would be another good format, but last time I checked the specifications for Opus in Matroska container have not yet been finalized; although through hearsay I think progress is being made.

Comment: fdk_aac is about as good as you're going to get (opus *might* get better results, but as LordNeckbeard noted there are currently MKV compatibility issues), but note that this will *still* give pretty poor quality -- listenable (especially if it's just recorded speech, like a lecture), but I wouldn't want to sit through an entire movie with this quality of sound.

Comment: @evilsoup Good to mention. I added a note to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering but when I launch the proposed CLI, I get the following error:
[matroska @ 0x26f8380] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: -80 >= -80
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
If I try to work with .mp4 files, the error doesn't occur, but I would like to work only with .mkv files. Any ideas to solve it?

Comment: @MarAja use the most recent build available, or compile ffmpeg, and try again. If it still occurs please post a question on [su] (make sure to include your ffmpeg command and the complete console output if you do post a question). See the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page for builds for Linux, Windows, and OS X, or refer to a [ffmpeg compile guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide).